# Is an ASP.net MVC View a "class"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

*...before everything, I'm doing this out of curiosity only. Nothing real-world application here, but just for knowledge and tinkering about...*

ASP.NET Views have properties like `Model` and `ViewData` and even has methods as well.

You can even use `@Using` just like a regular **class.cs** file.

I know that it is of type `WebPageView<TModel>`

My main question is: **is it a class?**

It should be because it's a type, **but**..

I should be able to also do this then (Razor engine):

```
@{
   public class Person
   {
       //etc...
   }

   var p = new Person();
}

<span>@p.Name</span>
```

**However I can't.. why?**

*note: currently a C#, ASP.net beginner.*

Comment: It is [now open sourced](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/03/27/asp-net-mvc-web-api-razor-and-open-source.aspx) so you can now [find out directly](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)!

Comment: The technical answer is, that the view code gets put into a method body. And you can't put classes there. But why do you want to define classes inside a view? That sounds dubious.

Comment: @CodeInChaos thanks. I would love if you could elaborate on that as an Answer here... I know there's no real good use for this, but I'm just trying to understand it more.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, what about the `functions` keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it because Razor markup is compiled into a sequence of statements inside a *method* within the generated class derived from WebViewPage or WebViewPage<TModel>

The more important question though, is why would you want to do this? Instead prefer to keep Razor free of this kind of logic - it's job should be to produce layout, not do any kind of business logic, or business data transformation. Do all the heavy lifting in your action method and deliver a Model that describes the data required to render the layout in a format that requires only simple Razor markup to process.

There are quite a few tutorials a round that describe how to approach MVC and Razor. I dug up this one that is brief but does a reasonable job of covering an end-to-end story that might help you get the idea. It does include using EF to get data as well which might be more that you were bargaining for - but it's worth a read to get the full picture of how a whole architecture hangs together: http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/06/developing-web-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-and-ef-code-first-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 14):

Sure, you need to use the `functions` keyword in order to drop down to exposing class-level things like fields, properties, methods, and inner types:

```
@functions {
   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
}

@{
   var p = new Person();
}

<span>@p.Name</span>
```

This will work just fine.

That being said, keep in mind that the only purpose of these inner classes is if you need to define a type only for use within a view.  Myself, I've never found a need to do this for classes.  However, I have taken advantage of this technique to add new methods that are not syntactically possible with `helper` methods.

Comment: whoa! never saw `functions` keyword before. It does compile! thanks :)

Comment: @JanCarloViray Please consider switching the selected answer to this one.

Comment: @JanCarloViray please note CodeAngry's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Views are classes. They are compiled into a temporary assembly (so they don't have access to internal members of the main assembly, which is good to know when dealing with dynamic/anonymous types).

I think that Razor has a rule that disallows declaring inner classes, haven't checked.